# Github won't let me clone my second repository (but no issue with my first repository)

Tags: github, repository, git-clone

I have two private repos on github. One of them works fine and I can clone it well. The second one which I just created, if I type

`git clone https://github.com/myusername/myrepo2.git`

gives me the error

`Cloning into 'myrepo2'... remote: Write access to repository not granted. fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myusername/myrepo2.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

How can I fix this? The exact same command but with using myrepo1.git instead works perfectly.

I can't find anything in the settings of my repository. By the way I had to use a personal access token (or whatever it's called) as password when I first set up the first repository (a year back). Not sure if I have to do something similar there.

I did check the other posts, but the solutions didn't help me.